ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'office365'
I am trying to run a Python program using below packages from a linux host :

from office365.runtime.auth.authentication_context import AuthenticationContext
from office365.sharepoint.client_context import ClientContext
from office365.sharepoint.files.file import File

The same program works fine in my Windows local setup. However in linux host its throwing a few errors :
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'office365'
Question is, can this packages work from Linux host ?
Tried installing 2 packages in linux host and getting errors :
pip install office365-REST-Python-Client
pip install office365
ERROR: Will not install to the user site because it will lack sys.path precedence to typing-extensions in /apps/tools/python/python36/lib/python3.6/site-packages
